# Change text box border when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I am making a website and would like the border color of the text boxes to change on hover and when they are clicked.

I have searched and found a few people showing the code for how to do it. I tried to run it from my LAMP server (dont know if embedded JS will work on a Lamp server) although it didnt work. The code was javascript which I don't really know so I couldn't understand what what was going wrong.

This is the code:

```
onload=function(){
    var inp=document.getElementsByTagName('input'), i=0, t ;
    while(t==inp[i++]){
        if(t.type=='text'){
            t.onclick=function(){this.style.border='1px solid red'}
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Is there a way to do what I am wanting just with CSS/html or will I need to learn JavaScript as well?

If its not too hard could explain how to do it or show me some example code?

Cheers - Cohen.

Comment: From the sound of it you should not even do this with JavaScript. Use css instead. A glimpse of your html would help though.

Comment: Do you want to add red border once the `<input>` is clicked and then keep it around forever after that?

Comment: @muistooshort No I want it to go away once they click off it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can be done using CSS pseudo-classes

Here is an example:

```
<style>
  .fancyText:hover{border:1px solid red;}
  .fancyText:focus{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<input type='text' class='fancyText' />
```

Comment: Newer versions, yes... IE6? No, it won't. :/

Comment: Do many people use IE6? I guess it wouldnt matter them not having these small effects on my site.

Comment: @Aaron only the hover works. It does not stay red when I click the text box.

Answer (score 0):

@Aaron is right, and you may visit w3school for css learning,

if you want it using java-script you only need function onFocus, onBlur and access the text box via id

```
function change()
    {
        var a = document.getElementById('fansy');
        a.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me although I dont really know JS so I probably did it wrong :/

Comment: @cohen: They have nothing to do with the real W3, they're just trying to sell people worthless certifications and they've managed to scam their way to the top of the Google listings, and they provide bad information, see http://w3fools.com/. A better resource is web things is https://developer.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use jQuery to make it simpler?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('type')=='text')
           {
               $(this).focus(function(){
                   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid red'}); 
               });
               $(this).blur(function(){
                   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid green'});
               });
           }
    });
});
```

Then you'll get multi browser support also....
Don't forget `<script src="[the_path_to_jquery_file]" type="text/javascript"></script>`
to include the jquery-file.

If you replace this

```
$('input').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('type')=='text')
           {
               $(this).focus(function(){
                   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid red'}); 
               });
               $(this).blur(function(){
                   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid green'});
               });
           }
    });
```

with this

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
          $(this).focus(function(){
                   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid red'}); 
               });
               $(this).blur(function(){
                   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid green'});
               });
    });
```

you will automatic get the inputs with attr. type = text.
[Here is more fact about jQuery attr selecting](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Whats the file extension for a jquery file?

Comment: .js, it's a build javascript lib.

Comment: Will this do it for all text boxes or do I have to say what their class / id is?

Comment: No, this is the good part with jquery. `$('input').each(function(){
` this function takes all the <input>'s and run along these, then if their attr. is text it will run the functions.

Comment: You could also set classes or ids like this. `$('#button').each(function(){....});` for ids or `$('.button').each(function(){....});` for classes.

Comment: Do I put the <script src="[the_path_to_jquery_file]" type="text/javascript"></script> part anywhere in the .php file with the text box?

Comment: Yes, or maybe inside the <head> tag... Recommended!

Comment: Do you have added the <script>-tag with the right path to your local/external jquery-file? Bump the hole code!

Comment: If the .js file is in the same dir as the php file would I write it like this? <script src="name.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and then I just put that in the head of the php file. Thats what I did and it didnt do anything :/

Comment: Okej, the jQuery file is named name? Not in the head of the php-file, in the <head></head> tag like this `<head><script src="name.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>your script.</script></head>` [See example](http://pastebin.com/7tjfF2Q7)

Answer (score 0):

```
#myTextarea {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#myTextarea:focus {
  border-color: red;
  outline: none;
}
```

In the HTML, the textarea element is given an ID of "myTextarea". In the CSS, the `#myTextarea` selector sets the initial border color to black and the `#myTextarea:focus` selector changes the border color to red when the textarea is clicked on and has focus. The `outline: none;` is added to remove the default outline that appears when the textarea is in focus.