# how to show and hide textbox-border

Tags: html, css

In table I have 1 column in which text-box is given so that user can edit text in that as per their need ,edited text is getting saved `onkeyup` properly but i want to hide text-box border ,or i can say after editing text text-box should not be visible ,only the edited text should be visible ,and if user again wants to edit than user should be able to see that text-box when user click on text again,something like this [I want textbox effect like this](http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2010/01/13/jquery-javascript-easy-edit-place-input-boxes-and-select-boxes),and i don't want to use jquery,how can i do this

here is my code for textbox

```
echo "<td ><input id={remark{$j}}  type=\"text\"  onkeyup=\"writeremark(this.id,{$data_set1['eid']},{$emprid});\" value=\"{$data_set1['remark']}\" /></td>";
```

#### onkeyup function

```
function writeremark(e,eid,emprid) {
    var val=document.getElementById(e).value;
    var dataString = 'eid='+eid +'&emprid='+emprid +'&val='+val ;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "updateremark.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(result){
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Hide the Border you can use Javascript. `onblur` event is what you need, onblur means when you remove focus from this input, either by clicking outside of it, or by pressing TAB to give focus to another element.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onblur="HideBorder()" onfocus="ShowBorder()" />

function HideBorder()
{
   var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").style;
   myInput.borderStyle="none";
}
```

Then when the user clicks back on it, you can use `onfocus`.

```
function ShowBorder()
{
   var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput").style;
   myInput.borderStyle="solid";
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onblur="HideBorder(this.id)" onfocus="ShowBorder(this.id)" />

function HideBorder(id)
{
   var myInput = document.getElementById(id).style;
   myInput.borderStyle="none";
}
```

As **Fiona T** suggested, you can do this in CSS (better solution).

Give your input a class.

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" />
```

Then in CSS:

```
.myInput
{
   border-style:none;
}
.myInput:hover
{
   border-style:solid;
}
.myInput:focus
{
   border-style:solid;
}
```

However, I suggest that you don't hide and show the border, because the size of the input may vary, you are technically removing the border which would be 1px,2px,3px...

So change the color instead of that, if your background is white, then...

```
.myInput
{
   border-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.myInput:hover
{
   border-color:#000000;
}
.myInput:focus
{
   border-color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: since my id is like this `id={remark{$j}}` so how do i write it can you please show it in your code

Comment: You can send the ID as a parameter just like you did with ONKEYUP, function(e) { var myInput = document.getElementById(e).style; ..... etc... }

Comment: It would be better to do this with CSS - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702195/change-text-box-border-when-it-is-clicked for a CSS example

Comment: your concept is right ,but i don't know why it is not working in my code ,i will try to find out mistake and will b back

Comment: I got it solved using css, Thanks for your response :),also thanks for suggesting about size of textbox